# How to use BatchingRabbitTemplate to increase publishing speed

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

My goal is to publish 50000 messages to an exchange. I send each message in a loop using `RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend`.

As this procedure took significant amount of time I began to look for an approach that would decrease it. I run against `BatchingRabbitTemplate`, created and configured it in the following way:

```
    BatchingStrategy strategy = new SimpleBatchingStrategy(1000, 1100, 3_000);
    ThreadPoolTaskScheduler scheduler = new ThreadPoolTaskScheduler();
    scheduler.setPoolSize(30);
    scheduler.initialize();
    rabbitTemplate = new BatchingRabbitTemplate(strategy, scheduler);
```

and continued to send each message in the loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
         ...
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("my-exchange", "*.my-key.*", message);
    }
```

But I didn't notice any increase of the speed after that.
When I used

```
        BatchingStrategy strategy = new SimpleBatchingStrategy(1000, Integer.MAX_VALUE, 30_000);
```

it was even worse than with a simple `RabbitTemplate`. It seems that I didn't configured it right. It would be great if anyone explain why it didn't lead to the expected publishing speed increase and/or suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `BatchingRabbitTemplate` is not a bean. And you don't provide a `ConnectionFactory` for it.

It is simply easy to place debug breakpoints into `BatchingRabbitTemplate.send()` and see what is going on when you send those messages.

Comment: I've omitted the configuration of `ConnectionFactory` in the example. I hoped that it would be obvious what the three parameters should be to increase the throughput.

Comment: OK. So, are you going to debug the program yourself or will you share with us a simple project to reproduce on our side? At the moment nothing obvious I see in your description.

Comment: Batching won't help if the performance is limited by the network bandwidth.

Comment: @GaryRussell Hm. I ran RabbitMQ in a docker container on my machine and published 50K messages to an exchange during some tests. However this question isn't very critical to me at the moment as the testing tasks are completed. Maybe I'll come back to it some day.